# How do I get this code to add to the salary of the employees as part of a list

Tags: python

Here is my code:

```
inputFile = open("Employees.txt", "r").read()
inputList = inputFile.split("\n")
fList = []

def listString(s):
    string = ""
    return (string.join(s))

for i in inputList:
    for x in i.split(","):
        fList.append(x)

for y in range (len(fList)):
    **if fList[y] == "90000":
        fList[y] = str(90000 * 1.05) + "\n"
    elif fList[y] == "75000":
        fList[y] = str(75000 * 1.05) + "\n"
    elif fList[y] == "110000":
        fList[y] = str(110000 * 1.05) + "\n"
    else:
        fList[y] = fList[y] + ","**
print(listString(fList))

file = open("Emp_Bonus.txt", "a")
file.write(listString(fList))
```

Employees.txt contains the following:

```
Adam Lee,Programmer,90000
Morris Heather,DA,75000
John Lee,PM,110000
```

I am trying to get the following output:

```
Adam Lee,Programmer,94500
Morris Heather,DA,78750
John Lee,PM,115500
```

The part of the code that is in bold is the problem, The input salaries need to be able to be different values instead of the code only working for the sample input. The input salaries have to be multiplied by 1.05. How should I go about doing this? Thanks!

Comment: You might want to save the data in a 2d list: `for i in inputList: fList.append(i.split(","))` Then later you can get the salary with `int(flist[y][2])`

Comment: @JohnnyMopp I'm not sure where exactly to put those two lines of code in, Could you elaborate, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way without any library. Just read lines of the file as a list using `readlines()` and then iterate each line. Only modify the last part after splitting it using `split(',')` e.g salary of each line and finally create the new file as per the requirements.

```
multiply, final_result = 1.05, []
with open('Employees.txt', 'r') as f:
    fList = f.readlines()

if fList:
    for line in fList:
        employee_info = line.split(',')
        name = employee_info[0]
        designation = employee_info[2]
        salary = float(employee_info[2].replace('\n','').strip()) * multiply
        final_result.append(f"{name},{employee_info[1]},{salary}")

if final_result:
    with open('Emp_Bonus.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.write('\n'.join(final_result))
```

**Output:**

```
Adam Lee,Programmer,94500.0
Morris Heather,DA,78750.0
John Lee,PM,115500.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I will like to use Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("Employees.txt",header=None)
df[2] = df.loc[df[2].isin([90000,75000,110000]),2]*1.05
df[2] = df[2].astype(int)
df.to_csv("Emp_Bonus.txt",mode="a",header=None)
```

Comment: I am not permitted to use libraries for this code, Is there any way to do so without external libraries?